# Android webview keyboard action when press "Go" button

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I show my webpage on WebView. My webpage has input tags.
When the input is active, the soft keyboard is shown.
I see the actions when I press "Go" button are different for Android 4.4 and 4.2.

- With Android 4.4, there's no action when I press "Go".
- With Android 4.2, the keyboard hide when I press "Go".

These different actions make not good for user experience. I want to control this. Is there any document describe the differences that I can refer? Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

What are your option for EditText.

In my device with 4.4 and 4.2, the keyboard hide when I press "GO".

Below is my setting for edittext:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/edit_input"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:imeOptions="actionGo" />
```

Comment: Hi, my case is webpage on WebView, not EditText in native code

Comment: Oh! sorry. I miss it.
But, when I press "GO" on 4.4, it is action, and no hide.